# django sub query filter using value from field in parent query

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filter

I have following models:

```
class Domain(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan, ....)

class Plan(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    num_ex_accounts = models.IntegerField(...)

class PlanDetails(models.Model):
    accounts = models.IntegerField()
    plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan, ....)

class Mailbox(models.Model):
    domain = models.ForeignKey(Domain, ...)
```

Any domain has a plan, any plan has N plan details which has accounts value for create mailboxes using a domain, I want to get in a queryset domains which exceed the accounts value, using raw sql the sql is like:

```
SELECT domain
FROM domain, plan 
WHERE plan.id = domain.plan_id 
  AND (
    SELECT SUM(accounts) 
    FROM plandetails WHERE plandetails.plan_id=plan.id
  ) 
  <= 
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM mailbox WHERE mailbox.domain_id=domain.id
  )
```

I tried in django something like this:

```
domains = Domain.objects.filter(
    Q(
        PlainDetails.objects.filter(plan = Domain.plan).aggregate(Sum('accounts')) <=
        Mailbox.objects.filter(domain = Domain).count()
    )
)
```

But it doesn't works, it throws an error about the Domain.plan, is there a way to reference that field value from parent query in the sub-query? is this queryset valid or is there another (better) approach? or I should use simply raw sql, what is the best option in this case?

Comment: what is a paret query? and also it's perfectly all right to use raw queries when you have to

Comment: Sorry I meant **parent** query

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Django 1.8 and higher, then try this:

```
Domain.objects.annotate(
    account_sum=Sum('plan__plandetails_set__accounts'),
    mailbox_count=Count('mailbox_set__id'))
).filter(
    account_sum__lte=F('mailbox_count')
)
```

Replace `plandetails_set` and `mailbox_set` with the appropriate `related name` if you explicitly specified any in the `ForeignKey` fields to `Plan`. Those two are just the defaults if none has been specified.

**UPDATE**
For very complex queries, it might be better to just run the actual SQL using cursors. Django ORM is usually good enough, but depending on the needs, it may not be enough. Please view the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in fact mailbox does not have relation wiht plan neither plan with mailbox, so get the mailbox_count as in your code not working, taking your code I think it could work if change that part as something like: `mailbox_count=Mailbox.objects.filter(domain=DomainFromParentQuery).count()` but I can not find how to reference `DomainFromParentQuery` or even if its posible

Comment: oh sorry about that. i misread and thought that mailbox has a foreignkey to `Plan`. Since it has a fk to `Domain`, just use `mailbox_set__id` instead of `plan__mailbox_set__id`. I edited my post.

Comment: Ok, thanks again for the update, now the query runs ok but is not giving the same results as the raw sql, its givin wrong values for the sum and the count, it seems its no taking the right related records, I am studying the issue to find whats happen.

Comment: Probably because of grouping. You can use `.values()` before `.annotate()` to specify how to group the records to compute for the aggregates. If unspecified, it should default to the primary key of your `Domain` model.

You can also print the SQL query generated by invoking a queryset's `query` attribute, e.g. `print(the_long_code_i_wrote_above.query)`

Comment: Watching the sql generated, I found to get the right result the count and sum parts must be `DISTINCT`, for the count case, it can be done using `Count('mailboxes_set_id', disctinct=true)`, but for `Sum()` adding such parameter does no difference, and it seems for sum theres no way to achieve the desire behavior

Comment: I do not have your complete code, so I cannot make my own investigation and give you better feedback. Whenever I hit a wall like this, I consider using multiple ORM statements and do some calculations using Python, revising my models, or just execute SQL directly. Just be reminded that by writing code that will directly run SQL, you forfeit the ORM features like queryset method chaining and such. Edited my answer to include link to docs for running SQL.

Comment: Finally I decided to use the raw SQL query, also evaluate using multiple ORM statements but considerign we have thousands of mails in db it will become a larger operation and for performance its better run just one query, so I will keep the raw sql in this specific case, thanks a lot for your help, was very useful (y)